# Processes on a CPU

Tags: linux, top, performance-tuning

How do I monitor/list the processes currently running on a specific CPU core. Basically I'm looking for an output similar to 'top' or 'htop' command but filtered for a specific CPU core id. Or the reverse of the command 'pidstat -t -p <process_id>' (this command shows the cores used by a process) but I'm looking for all processes running on a core.

Comment: Processes hop cores as the CPU scheduler sees fit, unless you have specifically set affinity.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did set affinity. I was trying to see if any other process got scheduled on that CPU.